# Needing compiled ImageMagick 7.1.0-19 Setup

Tags: windows, image-processing, imagemagick

I'm using ImageMagickObject COM+ on Windows.
This interface sadly was recently (2021) deprecated by ImageMagick !
cf. https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/main/ChangeLog.md#710-20---2022-01-22

I am desperately looking to download the latest version supporting it, 7.1.0-19 - 2021-12-22.
I am looking for the following compiled archives, but cannot find them on their website anymore

- ImageMagick-7.1.0-19-Q8-x64-dll.exe
- ImageMagick-7.1.0-19-Q16-x64-dll.exe

Could someone with a good soul give them to me ?

Many thanks... you would be a life saver !

Answer (score 0):

As stated here, https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/discussions/4967#discussioncomment-2388140

You can find the files here: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/actions/runs/1613048022 in the "Artifacts > installers" zip file.